# Flutter doctor is not detecting visual studio

Tags: flutter, visual-studio

I just installed flutter SDK on my windows pc and then I ran `flutter doctor` and I got this.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22000.739], locale zh-TW)
[✗] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

But I already got visual studio 2022 installed with "Desktop development with C++" on my pc.

**What I have tried:**

- Switch the channel to Master
- Install visual studio 2019 with "Desktop development with C++"
- Restarting the PC
- Reinstall visual studio 2022 with "Desktop development with C++"

Comment: try restarting the pc

Comment: Go defenitely for android studio or vs code, Visual Studio won't suit you as much as the other two.

Comment: don't worry its not required to install until you want to build windows app.

if you want to build windows app try to install Visual Studio Community version latest one. i hope it helps.

Comment: Please note that this is **not a discussion forum**. Please do not edit titles with "Solved" tags, since it is intended that questions can receive further answers at any time, even years later. The question is **not there** for the purpose of solving your problem; it is there to *help build a searchable library of questions and answers*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel oh sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same situation as you.
I solved the problem by bringing vswhere up to date.

In my environment, the following paths are affected.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

Here is the URL I used for reference

https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/releases
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102451